# How can you calculate the required tailplane force to ensure steady state flight?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, general-aviation, avionics, biplane

Consider a max forward and a max aft CG position.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just name the textbook and let us know which of your homework questions we should answer?

Comment: I wish there is a textbook for it.

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/mae5070/DynamicEquations.pdf

Comment: Any flight dynamics or aircraft design text book can help you here.
Check out Torenbeek, Etkin or Roskam. Basically if all you need is the force required and not control surface deflection or tail size all you need to do is a moment balance about the aircraft CoG